# Is there any command-line tool to sign transactions offline on a Linux machine?

Tags: transactions, signature, tools

I have an air-gapped machine with Ubuntu Server. Is there any command line tool which I can quickly download to sign offline transactions? Something like:

```
sign-tx private_key_file nonce=10 gasPrice=... gasLimit=... to=... value=... data=... chainId=1
```

This would output the signed transaction in hex.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of convenience, I've published a tool using `ethereumjs-tx` to sign a transaction from the terminal. It works as follows:

```
# install it
npm i -g ethereum-offline-signer

# sign a transaction
eth-sign NONCE VALUE FROM_KEY [TO_ADDRESS] [GAS_PRICE] [GAS_LIMIT] [DATA] [CHAIN_ID]
```

With the arguments formatted as follow:

```
- NONCE      : an int (ex: 7)
- VALUE      : a float in ether (ex: 0.01)
- FROM_KEY   : a 256-bit hex (ex: 0x9c22ff5f21f0b81b113e63f7db6da94fedef11b2119b4088b89664fb9a3cb658)*
- TO_ADDRESS : optionally a hex address (ex: 0xC08B5542D177ac6686946920409741463a15dDdB)
- GAS_PRICE  : optionally a float in gwei (ex: 10)
- GAS_LIMIT  : optionally a float in gas (ex: 50000)
- DATA       : optionally a hex (ex: 0x01020304)
- CHAIN_ID   : optionally an in (ex: 1)
```

[Here](https://github.com/maiavictor/ethereum-offline-signer) is its repository.

Answer (score 1):

`https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx` isn't a binary, but it's an easy-to-use node module available on npm.

`npm install ethereumjs-tx`

copy/paste the example code (with your modifications) into a node file, and have it print out the signed transaction.

`signed.js`

```
const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const privateKey = Buffer.from('e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109', 'hex')

const tx = new EthereumTx({
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
  value: '0x00', 
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057',
  // EIP 155 chainId - mainnet: 1, ropsten: 3
  chainId: 3
})

tx.sign(privateKey)

console.log(tx.serialize())
```

`node ./signed.js`

Comment: Thanks, I've published a command-line tool for convenience as explained below.